Implement Multi-Tenancy in API using Fief and FastAPI
I am working on implementing multi-tenancy in my API using Fief and FastAPI.
The GET /auth/my endpoint is designed to retrieve user information and validate access permissions through Fief.
@router.get("/auth/my", status_code=200)
async def my_info(auth: dict = Depends(oauth2_auth)):
    return auth

async def oauth2_auth(
    tenant: str = Depends(get_tenant),
    access: Optional[FiefAccessTokenInfo] = Depends(
        security.get_auth("dummy-tenant").authenticated(optional=True)
    ),
    info: Optional[FiefUserInfo] = Depends(
        security.get_auth("dummy-tenant").current_user(optional=True)
    ),
):
    if not access:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid authentication. Check that you are passing a 'Authorization' on your header.",
        )
    else:
        return {
            "oauth2_info": info,
            "oauth2_access": access,
        }


The tenant identifier is included in the API requests as a header.
The security variable contains a list of FiefAuth instances, one for each tenant. The get_auth(tenant:str) method returns the corresponding instance for the specified tenant.

How can I inject the tenant variable with a default value of 'dummy-tenant'? Are there any potential issues with this implementation?
About Fief: https://github.com/fief-dev/fief-python/blob/f190c53b8714bd9a51103ba6ead9351332a98bd3/fief_client/integrations/fastapi.py#L123
